# Find records for parent_id and update some fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Have table like :

```
type    ID   PARENT_ID    allowed
 0      1       0           0
 0      61      1           0
 0      148     61          1
 0      149     148         1
 1      100     149         0
 1      122     149         0
...     ...     ...        ...
```

Want select those `parent_id where allowed = 1` and find all records while root , and `if type = 0 set allowed = 1` . For example it must `set allowed = 1 where id = 61 and 1` . How to do it ?

Comment: Which version of MS SQL Server are you use?

Comment: @GeoVIP Speaking from my own experience the provided table structure is a pain in the ... try to work with lineage instead of parent_id's the lineage for the records above would be: /1/ ,  /1/61/ , /1/61/148/ ,   /1/6/148/149/ etc... so the children of 61 can be found by: where lineage like '/1/61/%' that's a very powerful scheme you've got then. The only drawback I've experienced is that you need a little bit more work if you are able to move nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL Server 2005 or newer, use recursive CTE to find all parent records up to the root, then perform the update:

```
WITH CTE (id, parent_id) AS
(
    SELECT id, parent_id
    FROM MyTable WHERE allowed = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MyTable.id, MyTable.parent_id
    FROM MyTable INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.parent_id = MyTable.id
)
UPDATE MyTable FROM MyTable WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM CTE WHERE CTE.id=MyTable.id)
SET allowed = 1
```

If you need to limit the recursion of the CTE (for example when debugging to prevent infinite recursion), you can use the MAXRECURSION hint. To do this, add the code `OPTION (MAXRECURSION x)` to the end of the statement. Here, `x` is an integer, specifying the maximum number of recursions before the statement is terminated.

Comment: Why do you store the ids in the temp table. Isn't it better to do an exists on the update directly with the CTE?

Comment: It will be good to mention in your answer about option maxrecursion.

Comment: @Arion Thanks - you're absolutely right. Editing my answer.

Comment: @Dan : Good that you edit that away. But I think that if you do not want to update the same row twice (in case the id is that same). Then change the `INNER JOIN`.... to `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM CTE WHERE CTE.id=MyTable.id)`. I also think that you should mention the maxrecursion like Hamlet Hakobyan said. See [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)